# How to not charge credit card through Stripe until another form is submitted (Laravel 4 project)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4, stripe-payments

I am trying to build a form that contains a Stripe payment button.  It is going to look something like this (imagine the finish button is faded without all the pertinent info filled out):

[image: Overall form]

Now what I want to do is have the user fill out their info above, then click on the Pay $1 button.  I want the user to fill out their cc info (and have this be easily checked), but I don't want them to pay now as the Stripe form shows.  I want this to just save their cc info and then, once finished, be able to click the "Finish" button on the above form to submit the payment and the rest of the info:

[image: Stripe form]

Is there any way to do this?

I am using the Abodeo Laravel-Stripe package to handle the payment: github.com/Abodeo/laravel-stripe

Here is some sample code:

View (doesn't have all inputs, just to give an idea):

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'fans.store')) }}

{{ Form::label('name', 'Name:') }}
{{ Form::text('name', null, array(
        'class'     => 'input',
        ));}}

{{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
{{ Form::text('email', null, array(
        'class'     => 'input',
        ));}}

//STRIPE BUTTON
<div class="button_row">
{{ Form::button('Pay $1', array( 
        'id' => 'customButton',
        'class' => 'button',
        )); }}
</div>

//Submit
<div class="button_row">
{{Form::submit('Finish', ['class' => 'button'])}}
</div>

{{Form::close()}}
```

JS Handling Stripe:

```
<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: '*************************',
    image: '/assets/images/1024icon.png',
    token: function(token) {
      // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
    }
  });

  $('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: '******',
      description: '**************',
      amount: 100
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
```

Server Side:

I currently have two functions in my controller that handle the other form input, and the Strip input separately.  I want this to handle all of that in one function (when clicking finish).

```
public function store()
        {

            $v = Fan::validate(Input::all());

            $full_name = Input::get('name');
            $name_pieces = explode(" ", $full_name);
            $first_name = $name_pieces[0]; 
            $last_name = $name_pieces[1];

            if ( $v->passes() ) {        

            $fan = new Fan;
            $fan->first_name = $first_name;
            $fan->last_name = $last_name;
            $fan->email = Input::get('email');
            $fan->save();


            return Redirect::to('/thisview);
            }
        }

        public function stripe_pay() {
            // Use the config for the stripe secret key
            Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('stripe.stripe.secret'));

            // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
            $token = Input::get('stripeToken');

            // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
            try {
                $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                  "amount" => 100, // amount in cents
                  "currency" => "usd",
                  "card"  => $token,
                  "description" => 'Charge for my product')
                );

            } catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
                $e_json = $e->getJsonBody();
                $error = $e_json['error'];
                // The card has been declined
                // redirect back to checkout page
                return Redirect::to('/artists/'.$artist_id)
                    ->withInput()->with('stripe_errors',$error['message']);
            }
            // Maybe add an entry to your DB that the charge was successful, or at least Log the charge or errors
            // Stripe charge was successfull, continue by redirecting to a page with a thank you message
            return Redirect::to('thisview/success');

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly - any reason you are not just using the Laravel cashier package: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/billing ?

Anyway - all you need to do is change your `store()` function - and simply save the Stripe Token you get `$token = Input::get('stripeToken');` into a session somewhere.

Then you can try and charge that token later on when the form is submitted. There is no need to try and charge the charge immediately.

Comment: @user1072337 - did that help with your question? Do you need more info?